# Returning model instances for a raw sql using Ruby Sequel

Tags: ruby, sequel

Is there a way to have Sequel return models instead of a hash for raw sql?

```
class Post < Sequel::Model
 def self.recent
  db["some sql goes here"].all #would like models returned here instead
 end
end
```

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: You mean the ruby gem sequel? Are you using rails? Have you got models defined somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Post < Sequel::Model
 def self.recent
  with_sql("some sql goes here").all
 end
end
```